# Get file another build from Go cd Artifactory using curl

Tags: curl, artifactory, go-cd

I want to download a file from go cd from another build (lets call it BUILD_A) and use it on my Master build (BUILD_B). For that I am using curl in order to fetch the file from Go cd Artifactory.

```
curl -u${user_name} -O "path/to/artifactory/xxx/builds/BUILD_A/${GO_PIPELINE_LABEL}/filename.xxx"
```

Now the issue here is that BUILD_B interpret ${GO_PIPELINE_LABEL} as its own build instead of build number from BUILD_A. So if BUILD_A is 65 and BUILD_B is 1001, it will take BUILD_B, in the end it will look like this.

```
curl -u${user_name} -O "path/to/artifactory/xxx/builds/BUILD_A/1001/filename.xxx"
```

BUILD_A is hardcoded in the curlpath.

So my question is if it is possible to get the file from another build in Artifactory and from the latest build_number?

Comment: Does your file name have versions? Have you configured the layout of the repository in artifactory to match your deployment layout?
If so you can try and use the resolve latest artifact REST API. 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

Comment: @Ariel The file name does not have any version. I am not relly that familiar with Artifactory, so I am not sure on how to match my deployment layout with my repository layout. Maybe I need to use GET command as can be seen in the link.

Comment: I think that you need to first make sure you have the right layout set on your repository, that way Artifactory will be able to recognize the latest artifact. Then you will need, as a pre-step to query Artifactory for the latest artifact, and use the value you received as your file.
I personally don't see any other choice but maybe others can.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins to poll repositories like Artifactory for updated artifacts for GoCD, for example this:

https://github.com/1and1/go-maven-poller

The go-maven-poller plugin is providing an environment variable that contains the URL of the artifact for CURL.

*(Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of this plugin)*

If you don't need Artifactory as the source, you should stay inside GoCD and fetch the pipeline build result from BUILD_A in BUILD_B. The reason for this is that polling will lose you time.

Using another pipeline as a material consists of:

- Adding BUILD_A as a material to BUILD_B
- Adding a fetch-artifact task in BUILD_B to actually "pull" the artifact.

See [here](https://www.gocd.org/getting-started/part-2/#fetching_using_artifacts) for more information.